# iPad (4.2.1 is overriding Base SDK to 4.3)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, ipad

I am trying to run my App on the device but when i was selecting the device it showed me this message "iPad (4.2.1 is overriding Base SDK to 4.3)".  Then i setted my Base SDK to 3.2 as there are only two options available (3.2 and 4.3) and also setted my deployment target to 4.2.  But when i build this application it showed me error:
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile (String) can't be found

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your installed provisioning profile.  It doesn't have anything to do with your SDK settings.

Either you don't have a correct profile installed, or it's expired, or the device you're trying to use isn't associated with it.

You should [read through this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW5) and make sure you've followed the steps.